# Spring 4 Annotation based equivalent of static resource mapping

Tags: spring, static, resources, annotations

I just converted an XML configured Spring MVC project to being annotation based but I cannot seem to figure out what annotation to use (and where to place it) for static resource mappings. The mappings in my project's older XML based configuration were:

`<mvc:resources mapping = "/css/**" location = "/css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping = "/images/**" location = "/images/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping = "/*.html" location = "/"/>`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Configuration  
@EnableWebMvc  
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

        @Override  
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
                registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");  
        }  
}
```

Comment: Instead of making a new class, I added the 'addResourceHandlers' method as a second method to my existing config class that already had an @Bean definition in it for the URL resolver. And this worked, thank you very much. Im just curious, is this considered good practice or should I have made it a separate class exactly as you described.

Comment: I would create separate configuration for each aspect of the application. One for the web part, one for the database stuff and transactions, one for the security etc.

Comment: Make perfect sense. Thanks again very much.